# Unfolding animation via CSS and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just discovered the OSX quote-expansion [animation](http://www.razorianfly.com/2011/02/28/mac-os-x-lion-mails-new-quote-expand-animation-video/) in the Mail app, and was blown away.

I'm determined to recreate it on the web (within a reasonable approximation), but don't know if anyone else has already done such a thing.

Two questions

1. If you're aware of any such animations (or similar ones), could you drop me a link?
2. For the time-being, I've begun using webkit 3D transforms as described [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/3d-transforms/), but of course they're limited to browsers supporting webkit. If you have any suggestions to improve browser support, it'd be much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: Extreme animations allways will require the following technologies in order of browser support: **SVG** (with Rapäel.js IE is presented with VML, but not shure about the 3D transformations), **Canvas** (but only in modern browsers, it lets you make diferentes transformations, including 3D transformations with WebGL, and **CSS3** (in webkit suports 3D animations). Or... flash... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in all modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/paperfold-css/launch